# How to remove WYSIWYG editor everywhere?

Tags: wordpress, editor, wysiwyg, text-editor

I would like to know how I can remove all of the WYSIWYG editors from everywhere (pages, posts, products, etc.)

[image]

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```php
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);

function init_remove_support(){
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor');
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor');
    remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'editor');
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Code is working fine on my end! Do you get any error running it? Or are you using a custom theme?

Comment: I am using a custom theme. Edit : Nevermind it works now. I don't know why ahah